# Should Qt track changes in resource at build time?

Tags: c++, qt

Say I have Qt set up, with `.qrc`s pointing to an actual `.png` file located on disk. It shows up in my application, and everything is going well. Should I now expect that any changes I make to that `.png` should show up after building and running the project. Or should I only expect these changes to show up after a full rebuild?

At the moment I have the latter behaviour, but can't find any explicit mention of whether Qt has some magic mechanism for tracking file changes? Or is this up to me in the build system to explicitly resources as dependencies to be watched by a target?

Edit:
The build system I'm using is sharpmake, and the configuration is very similar to this: https://github.com/ubisoft/Sharpmake/blob/dev/samples/QTFileCustomBuild/QTFileCustomBuild.sharpmake.cs

Comment: Dependency management while building your application depends on the build tools you use. To answer this, you should [edit] and mention what do you use to compile your application.

Comment: FYI: [Could Qt resource compiler (RCC) generate dependencies?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30807/could-qt-resource-compiler-rcc-generate-dependencies)

Comment: I'm using a `.pro` file and `qmake` to generate a Makefile, and I just tested (under MacOS/X) by touching a `.png` file my `.qrc` points to and then re-running `make`; I see that each time I do that, `make` re-runs `rcc` to create a new `.cpp` file from the `.qrc` file and then re-links my application, so it appears that a full rebuild is not necessary.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I have added to build software, but I didn't want to mention it because it's not a very common one. (Hence why there is next to no documentation for it)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It's a while ago that I fiddled with make files myself but I believe these dependency relations between `.qrc` and `.png` files should be expressed somewhere in the `Makefile`, shouldn't it? Though, I roughly remember I once saw separate dependency files for C/C++ sources (generated by gcc, I believe) but these should appear as a file as well.

Comment: If your build tool is downloaded from git hub, I see two options: 1. search or raise an issue in that github project 2. if the dependencies are not auto-recognized add a custom rule for that. I'm a bit familiar with `CMake`, and we managed to add custom build steps in our `CMake` files. With carefully prepared `CMakeLists.txt`s (denoting dependencies properly), it will generate the appropriate additions to the generated Visual Studio projects (Windows) and `Makefile`s (Linux) incl. proper dependencies. I would expect that other build tools support this as well somehow.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat if I search for 'qrc' inside my qmake-generated Makefile, I do indeed see lots of mentions of it there.